# I need to create an app for Playstore. As I click the App, It should redirect to web APP

Tags: android, web, webapi

How can I do this?
where should I start?

I already have a web app completely build and live, but now I need to create an APP for the play store which will redirect to my web API.

Answer (score 0):

We Can create it in Andriod Studio.
You can add the code in the onCreate() method of the MainActivity class in your Android Studio project.